# Spring Data Redis time to live with hashoperations

Tags: spring-data-redis

It looks like the latest version of spring data redis has removed timetolive (TTL) support for hash operations.

Earlier version of javadoc for `ReactiveHashOperations` mention 'expire' method, but latest versions do not mention ttl at all.

I can see ttl support for `ReactiveValueOperations` but not for hashoperations.

How can i achive ttl for hash operations ?